# Determining sample size of a Gaussian subset with new std

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, sample-size

I have N1 samples that is distributed close enough to Gaussian with 0 mean and std1. For simplicity, we can assume N1=1000 and std1 = 7.

Now I want to choose a subset of those samples that is distributed close enough to Gaussian with mean=0 and std2. Let's assume std2 = 12. The sample size of this subset is N2.

- Is there any analytical way to find N2 given N1 and std1, std2? For this problem N1=1000, std1=12, std2=7?
- Do you know if this problem is already studied? Do you know any published study/formula or anything about this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you choose a random sub-sample of any particular size from your original sample, why would you think the standard deviation of the sub-sample might be more than $7$?

Comment: The selection is not random. I am selecting the samples individually to make subset distribution similar to the desired distribution.